# Detect a wave in a data series

Tags: signal-processing, detection, wave

I'm looking for a way to detect a wave in a data series.

Example Series:

```
100, 110, 115, 110, 100, 90, 85, 90, 100
```

How can i determine if the series has a wave? I'm looking for a method or algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

One of the fundamental results of Fourier analysis is that *every* bounded function (ok, within limits set by the definedness of a specific integral) can be represented by a sum of oscillations (what you describe as wave).

The same goes for the discrete case: every finitely long vector of numbers can be constructed of sums of vectors containing an oscillation. To describe any N-long vector by the coefficients of these different oscillations, you need exactly N coefficients.

Hence, your question can generally be answered: yes, your series contains an oscillation. No matter what series you're looking at, that's always true.

If you want to know what frequencies are in your series, you'd typically either use the discrete fourier transform (DFT), or apply one of the several parametric spectrum estimators (MUSIC, ESPRIT). If you know the frequency you're checking for, Welch's method might be the appropriate reduction of the DFT for you.